# Uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected identifier?

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to correct the error the console is talking about can anyone help me. My code is below. I created a web form that saves the data to local storage and displays it on screen then deletes all the stored data if we want. But for some reason it won't take the data from the form at all.

```
// Wait until the DOM is ready 
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){
  // getElementById function
  function $(x) {
    var theElement = document.getElementById(x);
    return theElement;
  } // end theElement function

  function makeCats () {
    var formTag = document.getElementsByTagName("form"), // form tag is an array
    selectListItem = $('select'),
    makeSelect = document.createElement('select'),
    makeSelect.setAttribute("id", "groups");
    for(var i=0, j=notesCategories; i<j; i++) {
      var makeOption = document.createElement('option');
      var optionText = notesCategories[i]
      makeOption.setAttribute("value", "optionText");
      makeOption.innerHTML = optionText;
      makeSelect.appendChild(makeOption);
    } // end for loop
    selectListItem.appendChild(makeSelect);
  } // end makeCat function

  function getSelectedRadioBtn() {
    var radio = document.forms[0].favNote 
    for (var i=0; i<radio.length; i++) {
      if(radio[i].checked) {
        favoriteValue = radio[i].value;
      } // end if
    } // end for loop
  } // end get selected radio btn function

  function getcheckedBoxBtn() {
    if($('fav').checked) {
      favoriteValue = $('fav').value;
    } else {
      favoriteValue = "No"
    }
  } // end function

  function toggleControls(a) {
    switch(a){
      case "on":
        $('noteForm').style.display = "none"
        $('clear').style.display = "inline"
        $('displayLink').style.display = "none"
        break
      case "off":
        $('noteForm').style.display = "block"
        $('clear').style.display = "inline"
        $('displayLink').style.display = "inline"
        $('items').style.display = "none"
        break
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }

  function saveNotes() {
    var id                  = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000001);
    // gather up all form fields values and store them in an object 
    // object properites will contain an array with form labels and input values 

    getSelectedRadioBtn(); // calls function
    getcheckedBoxBtn();
    var item                = {}
    item.group          = ["Group", $('groups').value ];
    item.notetitle      = ["Title", $('notetitle').value ];
    item.noteinfo       = ["Note", $('noteinfo').value ];
    item.date           = ["Date", $('date').value ];
    item.items          = ["Number of Itmes", $('items').value ];
    item.attach         = ["Attach a File", $('attach').value ];
    item.favorite       = ["Favorite Note", favoriteValue ];

    // save data into local storage. Use stringify to convert our object to a string 
    localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(item));

    alert("Note Saved");
  } // end store data function

  function getNotes() {
    toggleControls("on");
    var makeDiv = document.createElement('div');
    makeDiv.setAttribute("id", "items");
    var createList = document.createElement('ul');
    makeDiv.appendChild(createList) // puts createList into ul element created above 
    document.body.appendChild(makeDiv) // attach makeDiv to the document 
    $('items').style.display = "block";
    for(i=0, entries=localStorage.length; i<entries; i++) {
      var createLi = document.createElement('li');
      createList.appendChild(createLi);
      var key = localStorage.key(i);
      var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
      var savedNote = JSON.parse(value); // parse the save note object back into an object 
      var createSubList = document.createElement('ul');
      var createLi.appendChild(createSubList);
      for(a in savedNote) {
        var creatSubListItem = document.createElement('li');
        createSubList.appendChild(creatSubListItem)
        var subText = savedNote[a][0] + " " + savedNote[a][1];
        creatSubListItem.innerHTML = subText;
      } // end for in loop
    } // end for loop
  } // end getNotes function


  function clearNotes() {
    if(localStorage.length === 0){
      alert("Move along buddy, nothing here to clear.");
    } else {
      localStorage.clear()
      alert("All notes are deleted");
      window.location.reload();
      return false;
    } // end if 
  } // end clearNotes function


  // Variables defaults 
  var notesCategories = ["--Choose a Category--       ","Grocery","Fitness","Entertainment","Dining","Shopping","Sports"],
  favoriteValue = "No";
  makeCats();


  // Set links and submits click events 
  var displayLink = $('displayLink');
  displayLink.addEventListener("click", getNotes);
  var clearLink = $('clear');
  clearLink.addEventListener("click", clearNotes);
  var save = $('submit');
  save.addEventListener("click", saveNotes);


}) // end main function
```

Comment: You probably missed a `;` or a `,` or a `(` or a `{` or a `)` or a `}`.

Comment: Give us a specific line number that the error occurs on.

Comment: @gdoron Apparently just a compiler/syntax checker ATM...

Comment: I *highly* suggest indenting your code.  Makes it **much** easier to read.

Comment: @Rocket. Please, don't answer those rude "questions".

Comment: @gdoron: I didn't actually "answer" it; I just wanna help =/

Comment: Can you just have a `;` on a line by itself?

Comment: Quick way to check syntax error is to use jshint. Online at http://jshint.com/ or downloadable as a plugin or npm package at http://www.jshint.com/install/.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are errors here :

```
var formTag = document.getElementsByTagName("form"), // form tag is an array
selectListItem = $('select'),
makeSelect = document.createElement('select'),
makeSelect.setAttribute("id", "groups");
```

The code must change to:

```
var formTag = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
var selectListItem = $('select');
var makeSelect = document.createElement('select');
makeSelect.setAttribute("id", "groups");
```

By the way, there is another error at line 129 :

```
var createLi.appendChild(createSubList);
```

Replace it with:

```
createLi.appendChild(createSubList);
```

Comment: I Was too slow. :P   PS jsbin is great for this! -> http://jsbin.com/ukibab/edit#javascript

Comment: @Dono - Note that you don't actually need separate `var` statements. One, with declarations separated by commas, is fine. The error here is just that the final comma should be a semi-colon.